# How to use checkbox as Radio Button in ReactJS with hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm Building a filter in ReactJS with hooks and now I need apply some style to the checkboxes.. The CSS is not the problem, I already did it in vanilla:

```
function checkOne(checkbox) {

    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('plan')

    checkboxes.forEach((item) => {

        item !== checkbox ? item.checked = false : item.checked = true;

    })

}

=======================================================================
                             X 3

                  <label for="premium">
                      <input 
                        type="checkbox" 
                        name="plan" 
                        onclick="checkOne(this)"
                        class="input-check" 
                        value="Premium"
                       >
                      <span 
                       class="checkmark" 
                       id="premium"
                      >
                         Premium
                     </span>           
                 </label>
```

Now I need to do the same think in react with hooks and I get stuck, I'm mapping a source of products and making a list of checkboxes form the product categories...

```
... 

const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false) //hook

...

handleChange(e, checkbox){
      setProduct(e.target.value);
      setSearch(e.target.value);      

 let checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('products')

    checkboxes.forEach((item) => {

        item !== checkbox ? setChecked(false) : setChecked(true);

    })
}

... in render method

      <div className="filters" id="top">
         {uniqueProduct.map(product => (    
             <label key={product.id}>
                <input
                      className='filters-available-size'
                      type="checkbox"
                      value={product.category}
                      onChange={handleChangeProduct} // <-- ?¿?¿ what should go here?
                      name='product'
                   />
                   <span className="checkmark">
                       {product.category}
                   </span>
             </label>
          ))}
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use checkboxes as radio buttons? I'm going to assume because of the styling--a design decision, perhaps. In which case, I would use radio buttons for the functionality and then use CSS to hide radio buttons and show checkboxes that reflect the state of the chosen option.

Comment: You're right, I wanted to see if it was possible to do it but it's not worth it in this case. Thanks for your help.